# Use of HTML5 in Android

Tags: android, html

I am started developing with android,and need to use HTML5 as a cross platform technology,but i dont know about HTML5 and its behaviour with android,I searched a lot but couldn't understand that from where should i start to learn . Any suggessions appreciated.
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you 

to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-

to-ask. If you've tried something already, 

please add it to the question - if not, 

research and attempt your question first, 

and then come back. Also manage the accept 

rate and upvote those answer that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check out http://www.sencha.com/blog/introducing-sencha-touch-html5-framework-for-mobile sancha touch for this.

On top of that http://www.sencha.com/blog/galaxy-nexus-the-html5-developer-scorecard/ is scorecard for the same.

you can also opt for Jquery Mobile to build HTML5 standard UI for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Write `Html5` code and put this in assets folder and use `webView` and load this open your html5 file in `webView`.This is quiet simple for more [watch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVqp1zcMfbE).